# Rejecting certain value from user integer input c++

Tags: c++

I have recently started to learn about C++ and so far I started on
data validation anyways I want
this program to reject the integer should the user enter 
said integer containing a 1 or a 0 e.g 1234, 0222
so I thought about it and came up with the code below.
However I now face a problem in this particular line

while (temp > 0 )

It would work if i was rejecting any other number say 2,3,4 
but since I want to reject 0 this becomes illogical.
How should i change the condition so that 0 will reject and ask the user to input again?

Edit: I managed to reject 0 or 1 in the middle of the integer e.g 234152, 234013

However I have no way to reject if the user enters 0234

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{

int n, temp, temp2 ,counter;
bool check = false;
counter = 0;
do
{
    check = false;                                          

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    temp = n;                                               
    temp2= n;

    while (!check && n > 0 )                                 
    {
        if( n % 10 ==1 || n % 10 == 0)
        {
            check = true;
        }

        else
            n = n/ 10;

    }


}

while(check == true || n < 0);
```

Comment: If you're trying to filter out certain characters from the input (why you want to is unclear) you should read the user input into a string and check that there are none of the characters that you want to reject. If you explain you're reason for wanting to discard the input it would be easier to guide you.

Comment: How about this: `while(n == 0 || check == 1);`

Comment: Ah right, this is for an class assignment the professor who teaches us wants us to use integer instead of a string as he have not taught us about strings yet. and while(n == 0 || check == 1) gave me an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best way of doing what you want to do. That being said, here is a quick way to fix your problem. After the while loop add an if statement.

```
if(temp==0)
```

that deals with the zero case separately.

Answer (score 1):

1) change `while (temp %10 == 1 || temp % 10 == 0)` to `if (temp %10 == 1 || temp % 10 == 0)`

2) `check` have not to be 1 in `do while` loop, or change its type to `bool`.

here is code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, temp;
    bool check = false;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> n;
        temp = n;
        check = false;
        while (temp >= 0) // changed here
        {
            if (temp % 10 == 1 || temp % 10 == 0)
            {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
    }
    while (check);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however entering 0 still breaks out of the loop and does not ask the user for input again

Comment: @eatmybananapls to fix it just change `while(temp > 0)` to `while(temp >= 0)`

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply however once entering certain values e.g 0222 the output now just hangs there.